# How to add an attribute data-slug = "$specfic_page_slug" in WordPress menu item?

Tags: menus, slug

I want to add custom attribute in WordPress menu item which has specific page slug. like this -

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101" id="menu-item-101"><a href="javascript:;">Meet The Therapist</a></li>
```

Change to

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101" id="menu-item-101" data-slug="$specific_page_slug"><a href="javascript:;">Meet The Therapist</a></li>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to add this on a menu *link*. The attributes for each link pass through the [`nav_menu_link_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_link_attributes/) filter.

You should be able to use it to add a custom one, along the lines of (not tested):

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item ) {

 // check if $item is what you need

 $atts['data-slug'] = 'something';

 return $atts'

}, 10, 2);
```

To change the whole list items you would have to use more general [`walker_nav_menu_start_el`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/walker_nav_menu_start_el/) filter, which only passes string you would have to cut up more messily.

Comment: Thanks, but still i do not know, how can i get slug name for each menu item. 
$atts['data-slug'] = 'something';

at the place of 'something'

Comment: Examine/dump `$item` and work your way from there. Your question is a little light on detail what you want and under which precise circumstances.